# What does the column 'Maint req' mean in TD Ameritrade's position table?

Tags: stocks, terminology, td-ameritrade

What does 'Maint req' mean in this TD Ameritrade position table? Am I losing money?

[image: TD Ameritrade position table]

Comment: You see the column that's titled "Gain"? It's green, and positive. You are ahead in both positions.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer What if he's trading using fully leveraged margin (70%/30%), and has held this position for 3-4 years?  Then it seems like he may have lost money?

Comment: Good point, but it took him this long to ask the question?

Comment: (shrug) I interpret the question as asking how to figure the margin into that profit (given the comment on my answer).

Comment: OP needs to find all accumulated interest to understand whether he's currently at a gain or loss. The image shown can't have that history. I'm in agreement on that. His first question is on maintenance requirement which he seems to not understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the maintenance margin required for that position.  Whenever you trade using your margin account, you must (by law, and also separately often by stricter policies from the brokerage) have a certain percentage of equity - at least 25%, often higher.  That protects the brokerage from significant losses if your position drops in value significantly (hopefully preventing the brokerage from failing outright in the event of a major collapse).  If the amount of equity falls below the maintenance requirement, you will have a margin call and be required to put some cash (or equity) into the account to maintain that level.

See [Maintenance Margin definition on Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/maintenancemargin.asp) for more information.

Comment: I sort of understand what this means after reading your answer and the Investopedia article.  But look at my table.  Does it mean I'm still making money if I sell my stocks at market values?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with making money or not - it's solely a requirement.  The only concern with a margin account that could impact 'making money' is what the cost of margin trading is at your brokerage (what they charge you to do it).

Comment: Do you know how to find that out? I'm confused what my net cost/gain of these two stocks if I sell them now at the market prices.  Can this be determined from this table?

Comment: Look at your brokerage agreement. I'm afraid I am not a day trader (and I use Vanguard for my retirement investments) so I don't know if there's an easy way to see your total costs for the margin account.

Comment: @qazwsx From [this page](https://www.tdameritrade.com/pricing/margin-and-interest-rates.page) it looks like you're probably paying 8-9% APR interest on your margin account.  So it depends on how much you're leveraged and how long you held these investments.

Comment: @Joe Yeah that's why I got rid of my earlier comment.  I hope that wasn't the answer he needed if so he should not be trading.

Comment: Where can I find out "how much you're leveraged." I've only owned these stocks for a month or so.

Comment: OK, I just figured out that my "margin balance" is just a few cents.  So I'm good.